# Error al subir imagenes con angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Al subir una imagen usando [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload), esta es subida correcta pero lo que deseo hacer es enviar mas datos junto con la imagen este es mi código:

```
$scope.crear_registro= function(){
    $scope.datos_usuario = (
      { 
        "username": $scope.data.vis_usuario,
        "password": $scope.data.vis_password,
        "nombres": $scope.data.vis_nombres,
        "apellidos": $scope.data.vis_apellidos,
        "identificacion": $scope.data.vis_cedula,
        "email": $scope.data.vis_correo,
        "telefono": $scope.data.vis_telefono,
        "celular": $scope.data.vis_celular,          
        "img_perfil": $scope.data.vis_file, 
        "id_canton": $scope.vis_id_canton                          
      }
    );
    $scope.upload($scope.datos_usuario);
  }
```

La funcion crear registro permite armar un json de los datos de mi formulario que luego `$scope.datos_usuario` es enviado a `$scope.upload`:

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(file))
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'http://192.168.1.8:3000/servidor/users',
            method: 'POST', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
            data: file //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
        }).then(function (resp) { //upload function returns a promise
            if(resp.data.error_code === 0){ //validate success
                alert("si")
            } else {
                alert('an error occured');
            }
        }, function (resp) {
            alert('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        }, function (evt) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            $scope.progress = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% '; // capture upload progress
        });
    };
```

Antes de enviar imprimo `file` el cual contiene los datos de mi formulario pero al llegar a mi servidor solo se me presenta la imagen pero no el resto de mis datos.

Como puedo solucionarlo?

De antemano les agradezco

Comment: intentastes de esta forma : `data: {$scope.datos_usuario },
                                                   file: $file}`

Comment: asi? data: {file}, file: $file} donde file = $scope.datos_usuario que se envia al metdo upload

Comment: correcto, pero por convencion cambia la variable a lo que realmente es presta a confusion

Comment: tengo un error en una llave }

Comment: data : { {file}, file: $file}

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberias separ la imagen del resto de los datos. En tu funcion `crear_registro` quita el atributo `img_perfil` del objecto `datos_usuario` y pasalo como argumento separado, asi:

```
$scope.crear_registro= function(){
    $scope.datos_usuario = (
      { 
        "username": $scope.data.vis_usuario,
        "password": $scope.data.vis_password,
        "nombres": $scope.data.vis_nombres,
        "apellidos": $scope.data.vis_apellidos,
        "identificacion": $scope.data.vis_cedula,
        "email": $scope.data.vis_correo,
        "telefono": $scope.data.vis_telefono,
        "celular": $scope.data.vis_celular,          
        //"img_perfil": $scope.data.vis_file, 
        "id_canton": $scope.vis_id_canton                          
      }
    );
    $scope.upload($scope.data.vis_file, $scope.datos_usuario);
  }
```

Luego en tu funcion `upload` recibe dos parametros, el fichero(imagen) y el resto de los datos, asi:

```
$scope.upload = function (file, data) { //si nombras el argumento `file` tal parece que recibiras eso, un fichero, pero en realidad recibes un objecto con mas datos
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'upload/url',
        data: {file: file, JSON.stringify(data)}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        //
    }, function (resp) {
        //
    }, function (evt) {
        //
    });
};
```

Tomada como referencia la informacion de la documentacion oficial de [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)